# Ubuntu nVidia Settings: Can't load info fram any available system

Tags: ubuntu, settings, nvidia

I just installed ubuntu for the first time. I also installed the driver for my nvidia graphics card, but when I try to go into the settings via:

```
nvidia-settings
```

it throws an Error:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

I tried:

```
nvidia-smi
```

Output:

```
Sun Nov 10 17:29:48 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.31       Driver Version: 440.31       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   33C    P0    22W / 250W |      0MiB / 11019MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also:

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

gives me:

```
Info: the nvidia profile is already set
```

---

I installed the driver directly, by downloading it and running:

```
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.31.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.31.run --no-x-check
```

that worked.

does anyone has an idea what to do?
Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally got it. nvidia settings can be installed easily via terminal and apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

did it.